# Windows Forms not Accessible while code is running

Tags: c#, .net

For instance, I have 2 Command buttons on my Windows Form, and a text box.
On Clicking the command button 1, the text box values keep on incrementing say from 1 to 1000000.

While this happens, I am not able to click anywhere on form, including the command button 2.
I can access the form again only when the counter stops at 1000000.

Please advice on this.

I also tried using a modelless form using `*.Show();` method.

This is my code to get values in TextBox.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    this.textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);

    label2.Focus();
    this.textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It's because you are running all your code on the UI, which then isn't able to process the display updates.

Comment: Applications are only responsive when they pumping messages. Your application can't pump messages if it's busy spinning in a loop in the middle of your code, unless you tell it to (but don't!)

Comment: If your code is running in the UI thread then, it will block until your code has finished running.  Look at the `Task` class for executing this in a separate thread. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are doing a task which takes some time to complete, in the same thread in which you want to rise an event (i.e. Click Button). In a single thread all tasks are done in a series fashion (one at a time). In other words, if one task completes then the other one is to be start.

To do so, you need to run this task in another thread (not in main thread). I hope this [DotNet Perls Link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread) 
helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with the UI from a different thread, you need to "marshall" the call to the UI thread, using a delegate and calling `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.

For instance, you could use:

```
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i)));
```

All the brackets get in the way a bit, so you might want to add an extension method like this, if you're using C# 3.0:

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, MethodInvoker action)
{
    control.Invoke(action);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
textBox1.Invoke(() => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main ("User interface") thread of a Windows Forms application is basically an infinite loop that processes messages from a queue.  When the user moves or clicks the mouse, presses a key, etc., the OS determines which application should process that input and adds messages to the queue for the appropriate application.  When notified that its message queue contains messages, the application processes the messages.  For instance, if a Windows Forms Control has received a click, it fires the Click event that is handled by user code.

This is where your code comes in.  In your example, you write a Click handler for the first command button that runs through a long loop updating the UI.  While your code is running, no other messages from the queue are being processed.  That means that clicks on other controls, like command button 2, are not being processed.  Only after your Click handler returns will the message loop continue processing events.

To keep the UI responsive, you could use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer set to a short interval and handle its Tick method by doing the work of one iteration in your loop.  That way you'd only tie up the UI thread briefly for each tick, and other events could be processed between ticks.

Alternatively, you could learn about doing work on background threads, but that may not be the best solution given that most of the work in your click handler is updating the UI.  It's not legal to update the UI from a background thread; methods that update the UI must be run on the UI thread by using `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, as discussed by Kai.